# NoReverseMatch (django WRONG URL lookup)

Tags: django, url

New to Django.
Using class based generic views to 'create' new songs and add them to the DB.

There seems to be a wrong url lookup. Am greatful for the help.

urls.py (look at the last URL - where the error occurs)

```
from django.conf.urls import url

import views
app_name= 'music'  # required for namespace
urlpatterns= [
  #/music/
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

  #/music/register
  url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

  # /music/71/
  url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

  #/music/album/add/
  url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

  #/music/album/2/
  url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),

  #/music/album/2/delete/
  url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$',views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),

  #/music/login/
  url(r'^login/$',views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),

  #/music/logout/
  url(r'^logout/$',views.logout_user,name='logout'),

  #/music/songs/all/
  url(r'^songs/(?P<filter_by>[a-zA_Z]+)/$', views.songs, name='songs'),

  #/music/71/add/
  url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add/$', views.SongCreate.as_view(), name='song-add'),
]
```

Attempt to go to the /music//add/ url to create a new song. Error shows no argument provided at 'detail' url.

views.py

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    login_url= 'music:login'
    redirect_field_name= 'go_to'
    model= Album
    template_name= 'music/detail.html'


class SongCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    login_url='music:login'
    redirect_field_name='go_to'
    model=Song
    fields=['song_title','audio_file']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        temp= form.save(commit=False)
        temp.album= self.request.album
        temp.save()
        return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The ERROR as displayed on going to URL : http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/17/add/ is

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/17/add/
Django Version:     1.11.12
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'music/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.15
```

The template in template/music from root project root directory is the one which wouldve loaded on success of URL /music//add/ is **song_create.html**  as is required by generic class based views.

```
{% extends 'music/album_thumbnail.html' %}
{% block title %}Add a Song{% endblock %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block right_to_thumbnail %}
```

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" >
  <li role="presentation" >
    <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">This Album</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#">Add a Song</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <h3> Add a new Song here</h3>
    {% if error_messege %}
      <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" acion="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="album" value="{{ album }}">
      {% include 'music/form_template.html' %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

The form-template.html file is as follows

```
    {% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2-col-sm-10">
      <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
      {{field.label_tag}}
    </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add/$', views.SongCreate.as_view(success_url=reverse('success-url')), name='song-add'),
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything in the CreateView to get the album from the URL and pass it to the template. You need to overwrite `get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['album'] = Album.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

You also need to modify `form_valid`, as there is no such thing as `self.request.album`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    temp = form.save(commit=False)
    temp.album = Album.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    temp.save()
    return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. 
Woudn't there be arguments to super() in the get_context_data return statement be SongCreate and self ?

Comment: In Python 3 those are optional.

Comment: Also, the song which Im trying to save to a particular Album of a particular User is not getting saved. Made changes to **form_valid** and added **get_context_data** as suggested. Still not working. Anything wrong in the code above(in question)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably the form is not valid. Are you showing the form errors anywhere? Post your form_template.html.

Comment: Have edited-in the form-template.html at the end of question.